# How to choose an appropriate electrolyte

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am looking to electroplate using a zinc-nickel coating using an ionic liquid as the electrolyte. How should I go about selecting the proper ionic liquid? I choose the metal coating due to it increasing the resistance to corrosion of the substrate being plated. Is it best to look at the properties of the possible electrolyte itself or how it reacts with the metal alloy?

Comment: Why would it react with the alloy?

Comment: Why a ionic liquid? It may cause significant restrictions.

Comment: The properties of an ionic liquid look like a potential alternative substitution for the electrolyte in electroplating. From what I've read this is due to it's properties such as having a low melting point, high conductivity, thermal stability, low vapor range, possibly lower toxicity if compared to other electrolyte elements, as well as a couple of other characteristics.